# More on the Existence and Uniqueness of the solutions of an SDE Proof

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

[image]

An extract from the proof of the existence and uniqueness of the solution of a SDE from Oksendal. I cannot see how holders inequality and the ito isometry are applied.

Comment: You have to also use the Lipschitz assumption on $\sigma$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The estimate by Fatou's lemma says that

$$
Y^{(n)}_t(\omega) \rightarrow X_t(\omega)
$$

in $L^2(\Omega \times [0, T])$.

Since $\sigma(t,x)$ is Lipschitz in $x$,

$$
\sigma(t, Y^{(n)}_t(\omega)) \rightarrow \sigma(t, X_t(\omega))
$$

in $L^2(\Omega \times [0, T])$ also. So Ito isometry tells you that

$$
\int_0 ^t \sigma(s, Y^{(n)}_s(\omega)) dB_s \rightarrow \int_0 ^t \sigma(s, X_s(\omega))dB_s
$$

in $L^2(\Omega)$.

The second claim about the path-wise Lebesgue integral is similar: it follows from Holder inequality that on a finite measure space ($\Omega \times [0, T]$ in this case), $L^1$-norm is bounded by $L^2$-norm. This shows convergence in $L^1(\Omega)$.